# Get text from DataGridView selected cells

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox, tostring

I have a DataGridView with cells from a database file that contains data. Basically, I want to get the text from the **selected** cells in the DataGridView and display it in a textbox at the click of the button. The code for the button click event is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SelectedThings As String = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString
    TextBox1.Text = SelectedThings
End Sub
```

However in **TextBox1** I get:

> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection

I'm thinking it isn't as simple as it seems. I'm a C developer just learning VB.NET.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DataGridView.SelectedCells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx) is a collection of cells, so it's not as simple as calling `ToString()` on it. You have to loop through each cell in the collection and get each cell's value instead.

The following will create a comma-delimited list of all selected cells' values.

**C#**

```
TextBox1.Text = "";
bool FirstValue = true;
foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in DataGridView1.SelectedCells)
{
    if(!FirstValue)
    {
        TextBox1.Text += ", ";
    }
    TextBox1.Text += cell.Value.ToString();
    FirstValue = false;
}
```

**VB.NET** ([Translated](http://www.kamalpatel.net/ConvertCSharp2VB.aspx) from the code above)

```
TextBox1.Text = ""
Dim FirstValue As Boolean =  True 
Dim cell As DataGridViewCell
For Each cell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
    If Not FirstValue Then
        TextBox1.Text += ", "
    End If
    TextBox1.Text += cell.Value.ToString()
    FirstValue = False
Next
```

Comment: So I have to find each cell that the user selects?

Comment: Kind of, but that's not exactly how I'd put it. You don't have to "find" the cells, as a reference to them is presented to you in the collection.

Comment: Minor improvement in the VB.NET version: &= instead of += (both work of course).

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
Dim i = Datagridview1.currentrow.index
textbox1.text = datagridview1.item(columnindex, i).value
```

It should work :)

Answer (score 5):

Simply

```
MsgBox(GridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                                    Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    MsgBox(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in case you just need the value of the first seleted sell (or just one selected cell if one is selected)

```
TextBox1.Text = SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

or, we can use something like this

```
dim i = dgv1.CurrentCellAddress.X
dim j = dgv1.CurrentCellAddress.Y
MsgBox(dgv1.Item(i,j).Value.ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the answers on this page only apply to a single cell, and OP asked for **all** the selected cells.

If all you want is the cell contents, and you don't care about references to the actual cells that are selected, you can just do this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SelectedThings As String = DataGridView1.GetClipboardContent().GetText().Replace(ChrW(9), ",")
    TextBox1.Text = SelectedThings
End Sub
```

When `Button1` is clicked, this will fill `TextBox1` with the comma-separated values of the selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the ToString() will return the name of the object retruned by the SelectedCell Property.( a collection of the currently selected cells).

This behavior occurs when an object has no specific implenetation for the ToString() methods.

in our case, all you have to do is to iterate the collection of the cells and to accumulate its values to a string. then push this string to the TextBox.

have a look here how to implement the iteration:

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

the Best of both worlds.....

```
Private Sub tsbSendNewsLetter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsbSendNewsLetter.Click
        Dim tmpstr As String = ""
        Dim cnt As Integer = 0
        Dim virgin As Boolean = True
        For cnt = 0 To (dgvDetails.Rows.Count - 1)
            If Not dgvContacts.Rows(cnt).Cells(9).Value.ToString() Is Nothing Then
                If Not dgvContacts.Rows(cnt).Cells(9).Value.ToString().Length = 0 Then
                    If Not virgin Then
                        tmpstr += ", "
                    End If
                    tmpstr += dgvContacts.Rows(cnt).Cells(9).Value.ToString()
                    virgin = False
                    'MsgBox(tmpstr)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Dim email As New qkuantusMailer()
        email.txtMailTo.Text = tmpstr
        email.Show()
    End Sub
```